# Wso2 Outlookmail connector

Tags: wso2, connector, wso2-esb

I try to use Outlook mail api connector but it not work for me. I cannot manage to connect. I follow the documentation and I still stuck, I receive a http 401.1 error . In the init component, I fill client_id and secret_id, but I don't Know where to find access token. I try with oauth sand box, I generate an token and fill it to init conponent in the esb connector and it work.
But never manage, to make it work without aouth sand box.

Any help, thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Office365+Authenticator) to associate an Azure subscription with Office 365 account (Azure AD) or create a new Azure subscription and associate it with your Office 365 account.

Comment: Hello, I use WSO2 ESB to connect to office 365. I manage to make work outlook api but after 1 hour, the token expire and then I must for a new token. Is there an way, that the init component in the esb get automaticaly an new token ?

Comment: Hi, Once you get access token, you need to pass that token along with your refresh token, client id and client secret, in init method we automate it to get an access token from refresh token once it gets expired.

Important thing is that you need to pass access token in init method as soon as you get the token or optionally you may set the intervalTime in init methods that should be less than 1 hour.

Comment: Hi, it still don't work for me. I follow all the steop to get an acess token and an refresh token. I fill my init conf file with them and after 1 hour, I get 401 :reason="The token has expired.";error_category="invalid_lifetime"

Comment: here is my init conf :

Comment: <localEntry key="init_mail" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <outlookmail.init>
        <accessToken>accesstoken</accessToken>
        <apiUrl>https://outlook.office.com/api</apiUrl>
        <apiVersion>v2.0</apiVersion>
        <refreshToken>refreshToen</refreshToken>
        <clientSecret>clientsecret</clientSecret>
        <clientId>cliebntid</clientId>
        <redirectUri>redirectUri</redirectUri>
        <resource></resource>
        <registryPath></registryPath>
        <intervalTime>50</intervalTime>
    </outlookmail.init>
</localEntry>

Comment: Hi, Once you get access token , you need to fill the init config and make some call to access the outlook resources (E.g createFolder), while you are making call, the value of the access_token, refresh_token and the current system time are stored in the ESB registry. If you want to get a new token , in the next call you can set the intervalTime. that should be less than 1 hour and its unit is in the millisecond.

Comment: In the local entry:
<outlookmail.init xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
 <apiUrl>https://outlook.office.com/api</apiUrl><apiVersion>v2.0</apiVersion>
<refreshToken>refreshToken</refreshToken>
<clientSecret>client_secret</clientSecret>
<clientId>client_Id</clientId>
 <resource>https://outlook.office.com/</resource>
<redirectUri>https://localhost:9443/commonauth</redirectUri>
<accessToken>accessToken</accessToken>
<registryPath>Connector/OutlookMailRegPath</registryPath>
 <intervalTime>1000</intervalTime>
</outlookmail.init>

Comment: If you want to get new access token within one hour, you can change the value of the intervalTime(E.g 300000(5 minutes)), you will find the new access token in the registry.

Comment: Ok, it work. I made an mistake, when I called for an token, I used https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/v2.0/token and not https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token. So, all is working now, that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For getting an access_token, you have to associate an Azure subscription with Office 365 account (Azure AD). You may refer [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210517021355/http://vsvives.blogspot.com/).

once you get cliend_id and client_screte, you may refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/exchangedev/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-office-365-exchange-online) (step two and three)  to get an access_token and refresh_token.